# I want to reverse the rounded corner in Android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-view, cornerradius

I have tried with layerlist but don't know which syntax can help me to implement my desired shape.
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022807/how-to-make-inner-radius-for-a-rectangle-shape